# z-index для дочернего элемента с fixed

Tags: css

Есть следующий код

```css
.bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    z-index: -2;
}
.wrap{
    border: 10px solid;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 100px;
    
}
.el{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Мне нужно скрыть элемент `el` под блок `bg`. Как можно этого добиться?

Comment: Нужно что-бы он скрывался по какому-то событию, или всегда? Если всегда - то смотрите ответ ниже. Если по событию - поправьте ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ответ ниже не сработает. Думаю это как-то связано с контекстом или с чем-то в этом роде

Comment: А вы и не сможете, меняйте структуру, у Вас `.wrap` перекроет все и вся из-за своего z-index

Comment: Тут особенность в том, что даже если убрать z-index для wrap, ничего не поменяется из-за fixed(((

Comment: Есть мысли, как поменять?

Comment: @DaemonHK, ну у wrap нет `z-index`... UPDATE: Нашёл в прошлой версии вопроса. Но в новой нет и всё равно не работает)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я немного поменял структуру, чтобы все не цеплялись к этому z-index, тоже понимаю, что дело не только в нем было

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: -2;
}
.wrap{
  border: 10px solid;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 100px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.el{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: А вы сами этот пример проверили?

Answer (score 0):

z-index работает для соседних элементов с позиционированием absolute , fixed и relative. Соседний блок для div.bg это div.nav , соответственно для решения проблемы нужно добавить следующий код стилей:

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -4;
}
```

Comment: Это скроет весь блок целиком, нужно спрятать отдельно el

Comment: С помощью z-index и position при такой структуре элементов не получится этого сделать

Comment: В этом и вопрос, есть варианты, как добиться желаемого?

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такой вариант:

```
.bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    z-index: -2;
}
.wrap{
    border: 10px solid;    
    padding: 100px;
    }
.el{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red; 
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: -4;
}
```

Comment: А есть еще вариант wrap поставить absolut, но и то и другое кардинально меняет верстку и не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать `.wrap` `absolute` и для `.el` добавить `z-index`:

```css
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    z-index: -2;
}

.wrap {
    border: 10px solid;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 100px;
}

.el {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: -3;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Это, пожалуй самый близкий вариант, но к сожалению, нужна фиксированная позиция(